# Truncating URL with Jquery Ajax Call

Tags: jquery

Here is my URL:

```
http://www.mydomian.com/sp.asp?type=100&code=11&search=&cname=somevalue&cvalue=somevalue;
```

now from this url, when i go to next page through ajax call, i want it to be executed but it should remove the `&cname=somevalue&cvalue=somevalue` while calling the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's always on the end of the URL you can get rid of it easily by splitting:

```
var url = "http://www.mydomian.com/sp.asp?type=100&code=11&search=&cname=somevalue&cvalue=somevalue;";
url = url.split("&cname")[0];
console.log(url);
```

This however depends on your sitation and it's not very clean. The most proper way would probably be to prevent it from adding it to the URL in the first place.